# save signature as image iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image, graphics, core-graphics

I want to create an app that includes a signature submission as image, I've tried [tutorial from ray](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit). How can I create such a signature drawing and save as image. I have used `UIImageView` with main screen size and `touchesBegan`,    `touchesMoved`, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`to draw images. that works nicely but I don't want to use an image with large size as screen size. When I try to reduce the size of `imageView` edit others accordingly as `contextSize` but I get unexpexted images, somebdy please help me to get rid of tis problem

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem using Ray's solution, but using a uiview subclass. Now I would like to know How to trace path using `UIBezierPath`.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: u can always resize image using core graphics. 
[link](https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories/blob/master/UIImage%2BResize.m) ..

Comment: Thanks rahul_send89 for the link.>

I,he used other way to solve this as I create A `UIView`subclass and added touch methods..